# Smallest $m>1$ such that the number of Collatz steps needed for $238!+m$ to reach $1$ differs from that for $238!+1$.

Tags: collatz-conjecture

Let $h(x)$ be the number of steps^ needed for $x$ to reach $1$ in the [Collatz/3n+1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) problem. I found that

$$h(238!+n)=h(238!+1), \;\; \forall 1 < n \leq 690,000,000$$
Here "!" is the standard factorial.

This is a lot of consecutive terms with the same height and beats the [current record](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470782/longest-known-sequence-of-identical-consecutive-collatz-sequence-lengths/3734818#3734818) by far. Now I am wondering:

> What is the smallest $m > 1$, such that $h(238!+m) \neq h(238!+1)$?

I don't know of an efficient way of finding it. We know that $h(2\cdot(238!+1))=h(238!+1)+1$, so $m \leq 238!+1$, but that's a rather large upper bound.

UPDATE 16/08/2021: Martin Ehrenstein found that $10^9 < m < 10^{94}$. See [A346775](https://oeis.org/A346775). Later user mjqxxxx improved the upper bound to $m \leq 2^{64}$.

UPDATE 21/08/2021: Martin Ehrenstein improved the upper bound to $m < 11442739136455298475$.

^ $3x+1$ is considered one step and $x/2$ is one step.

Comment: Thank you for the edits!

Comment: I think you should call a mathematician. There may actually be more interest in HOW you found this.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet my method is not very exciting. I used a simple brute force program that iterates through all the factorials. I got stuck at $238!$ and realized I need help. I am hoping that this information could be useful for someone working on the Collatz problem.

Comment: $2^{232}x+r$ might help.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee can you provide more information please?

Comment: Parity falls to $r$ so it mostly follows the sequence of $r$ are remainders until you use up the exponent on $2$ , and every multiply by $3$ and add $1$ step, you add a factor of $3$ in the lead coeffient.

Comment: I’m going to conjecture that $m=2^{64}$ is the smallest.  (Certainly it’s a much improved upper bound.)

Comment: @mjqxxxx that's a great find!

Comment: Are factorials more likely than other integers to begin a sequence of consecutive integers which all have the same number of Collatz steps? If so, why?

Comment: @SeekingAnswers great question. So far I have only investigated powers of two (https://oeis.org/A277109) and factorials (https://oeis.org/A346775). Powers of two seem to have more patterns and are perhaps more predictable, while factorials look more chaotic. Both give many consecutive terms with the same height.

Comment: Factorials are rich in powers of $2$ letting $m$ decide parity.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee hmmm but powers of 2 are also rich in powers of 2 :) so I am not convinced that factorials will give more terms.

Comment: Please add explicite information, whether you use counting by "*$(3x+1)/2$ is one step*"   or by "*$3x+1$ is one step*"

Comment: @GottfriedHelms $3x+1$ is one step and $x/2$ is one step. I will add this in.